# Tasks now have a due TIME as well as DATE but API still says 00:00:00

Tags: google-tasks-api

I noticed today that an updated iOS version of the Google Tasks app includes the option to set the time in addition to the due date. A welcome improvement, and the due datetime from the iOS app properly appears on the Gsuite website. But, I don't see the time when getting the Task from the API.

Should the API be returning the proper time? All I get is 00:00:00 the same as always.

If it matters, I'm using the PHP API client. Just updated today with composer to be sure I had the most current version.

Comment: I ran into the same thing today. I've been tinkering with a script and needed the time field. Thought I was good to go when the change rolled out this week. Looks like it hasn't been implemented in the public api. I filed a bug report with Google today. Holding my breath.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Very glad to hear that it's not just me. Hope they get it working soon - time it pretty important in our application.

Comment: @WayneCulbreth could you link me to that bug report?

Comment: Found it. You can vote on Google's public issue tracker to make this data accessible via the API. The issue is here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128979662. You can vote on the issue if you are affected by it.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, according to Google's documentation for the Tasks API:

> The due date only records date information; the time portion of the timestamp is discarded when setting the due date. It isn't possible to read or write the time that a task is due via the API.

https://developers.google.com/tasks/reference/rest/v1/tasks#resource:-task